# C3js horizontal bar chart labels cut off and sizing issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I have a fixed size horizontal bar chart with rather long labels.

Main Question: 
The label with the biggest data always gets cut off.

Additional Question (only nice to have.. ;) Is it possible in C3 to add margin between the bars?

Example with labels been cut off:

```js
 var colors = ['#0065A3', '#767670', '#D73648', '#7FB2CE', '#00345B'];
var padding = 5;


data= [
['veryveryveryveryverylongdatalabel01', 439034],
['veryveryveryveryverylongdatalabel02', 413664],
['veryveryveryveryverylongdatalabel03', 351376],
['veryveryveryveryverylongdatalabel04', 349932],
['veryveryveryveryverylongdatalabel05', 316490],
['veryveryveryveryverylongdatalabel06', 315039],
['veryveryveryveryverylongdatalabel07', 285908],
['veryveryveryveryverylongdatalabel08', 285681],
['veryveryveryveryverylongdatalabel09', 285215],
['veryveryveryveryverylongdatalabel10', 203248],
['veryveryveryveryverylongdatalabel11', 200508],
['veryveryveryveryverylongdatalabel12', 195508],
['veryveryveryveryverylongdatalabel13', 195058],
['veryveryveryveryverylongdatalabel14', 193508],
['veryveryveryveryverylongdatalabel15', 185508],
['veryveryveryveryverylongdatalabel16', 180508],
['veryveryveryveryverylongdatalabel17', 177508]
];

var totalDataValue = 0
data.forEach(function(d){
 totalDataValue+=d[1];
});


var chart1 = c3.generate({
  bindto: d3.select('#chart1'),
  data: {
    columns: data,
    type: 'bar',
    labels: {format : function(v, id) {return id + ": " + d3.format(",.0f")(v) + " ["+d3.format(".2%")(v/totalDataValue)+"]"; }}
  },
  bar: {
   width: { ratio: 1}
  },
  legend: {
    show: false,
  },
  tooltip: {
    show: true,
    format: {
      value: function(value) {
        return d3.format(",.0f")(value);
      }
    }
  },
  zoom: {
    enabled: true
  },
  axis: {
    x: {
      show:false,
      type:'category',
      categories: ['value1']
      },
    y: {
      show:false
    },
    rotated: true
  }
  });
```

```css
#chart1 {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.7.10/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.7.10/c3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart1" class "c3">

</div>
```

It seems to be an internal C3 sizing issue. 
Am I right there? 
Is there a way to prevent the labels from beeing cut off?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for preventing the labels from being cut-off.
Please see my following post on this:
[Calculate padding for C3js horizontal bar charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61344514/calculate-padding-for-c3js-horizontal-bar-charts)

It's based on using global chart padding instead of using y-axis padding and turning off clip-path

Answer (score 1):

You can set Y Axis top padding.

```
axis: {
    y: {
        padding : {
            top: 430
        }
    },
    rotated: true
  }
```

You can also calculate top padding value based on length of largest label.

Comment: thank you. this might be a valid approach.
Nevertheless I currently do not have a solution how to calculate the padding. We'll see ;)

Comment: @gothmogg I had similar case. I found out padding required for various length labels by actually setting value, for at least 4-5 different lengths. And then I came up with one formula based on length of label which I applied on largest label length in my set. This approach might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an empty space by using a couple of **"\u00A0"** at the end of your labels format function:

```
data: {
labels: {format : function(v, id) {return id + ": " + d3.format(",.0f")(v) 
+ " ["+d3.format(".2%")(v/totalDataValue)+"]"+"\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0"; }}
},
```

To set some space between the bars, add the bar.space parameter:

```
bar: {
    space: 0.2
}
```

Below the code sipped:

```js
var colors = ['#0065A3', '#767670', '#D73648', '#7FB2CE', '#00345B'];
var padding = 5;

data= [
['veryveryveryveryverylongdatalabel01', 439034],
['veryveryveryveryverylongdatalabel02', 413664],
['veryveryveryveryverylongdatalabel03', 351376],
['veryveryveryveryverylongdatalabel04', 349932],
['veryveryveryveryverylongdatalabel05', 316490],
['veryveryveryveryverylongdatalabel06', 315039],
['veryveryveryveryverylongdatalabel07', 285908],
['veryveryveryveryverylongdatalabel08', 285681],
['veryveryveryveryverylongdatalabel09', 285215],
['veryveryveryveryverylongdatalabel10', 203248],
['veryveryveryveryverylongdatalabel11', 200508],
['veryveryveryveryverylongdatalabel12', 195508],
['veryveryveryveryverylongdatalabel13', 195058],
['veryveryveryveryverylongdatalabel14', 193508],
['veryveryveryveryverylongdatalabel15', 185508],
['veryveryveryveryverylongdatalabel16', 180508],
['veryveryveryveryverylongdatalabel17', 177508]
];

var totalDataValue = 0
data.forEach(function(d){
 totalDataValue+=d[1];
});


var chart1 = c3.generate({
  bindto: d3.select('#chart1'),
  data: {
    columns: data,
    type: 'bar',
    labels: {format : function(v, id) {return id + ": " + d3.format(",.0f")(v) + " ["+d3.format(".2%")(v/totalDataValue)+"]"+"\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0"; }}
  },
 bar: {
    width: { ratio: 1},
    space: 0.2
  },
  legend: {
    show: false,
  },
  tooltip: {
    show: true,
    format: {
      value: function(value) {
        return d3.format(",.0f")(value);
      }
    }
  },
  zoom: {
    enabled: true
  },
  axis: {
    x: {
      show:false,
      type:'category',
      categories: ['value1']
      },
    y: {
      show:false
    },
    rotated: true
  }
  });
```

```css
#chart1 {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.7.10/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.7.10/c3.min.js"></script>

<body>
<br><br>

<div id="chart1" class "c3">
```

Comment: Thank you, but adding "\u00A0" does not really work because the labels do not have a fixes length and the number of "\u00A0" therefore needs to be variable. I think I'll each out to C3 and open an issue there.

Comment: What about setting the number of "\u00A0" dynamically depending on the length of the label name. I assume your label names won't be longer than the ones in your example (around 35 letters) - so adding four or five "\u00A0" would be sufficient for the longest case. You could easily write a function for this.